# When hostvars data is populated and how it is accessible?

Tags: ansible

Here is my play:

```
- name: Tag ec2 instances 
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Print Hosts
      debug: var=hostvars[item]['ec2_id']
      with_inventory_hostnames: all

    - name: Print Hosts 2
      debug: msg={{hostvars[item]['ec2_id']}}
      with_inventory_hostnames: all

    - name: Tag Hosts
      ec2_tag:
        resource: "{{ hostvars[item]['ec2_id'] }}"
        region: ap-southeast-2
        args:
          tags: {mytag: 'myvalue'}
      with_inventory_hostnames: all
```

Can anyone explain why the second task fails with the following error while the first one is successful?

```
...
ok: [localhost] => (item=172.31.11.37) => {
    "hostvars[item]['ec2_id']": "i-xxxxxx", 
    "item": "172.31.11.37"
}

TASK [Print Hosts 2] ***********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'ec2_id'"}
```

Comment: can't understand! The same object is used for both tasks but failed on the second task.

Comment: thanks user2864740. I see what u mean. Going to change the question title to "When hostvars data is populated and how it is accessible?"
Any suggestion on how to fix this please?

Comment: To get it work:
`- name: Tag ec2 instances 
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Print Hosts
      debug: var=hostvars[item]['ec2_id']
      with_inventory_hostnames: all
      register: ugly

#    - name: New Print Hosts
#      debug: msg={{item["hostvars[item]['ec2_id']"]}}
#      with_items: ugly.results

    - name: Tag Hosts
      ec2_tag:
         state: present
         resource: "{{ item[\"hostvars[item]['ec2_id']\"] }}"
         region: ap-southeast-2
         tags:
           ShutDownAfterHours: No
      with_items: ugly.results`

Comment: You can answer your own question, but don't put the answer in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debug` module with `var=hostvars[item]['ec2_id']` will not fail if anything to the right of equal sign is undefined.
While `msg={{hostvars[item]['ec2_id']}}` will fail if the part in braces can't be templated.

In your example this may fail for `localhost` because I'm almost sure that `ec2_id` is not defined for localhost.

To avoid this, you can apply `when` statement to your loop, as follows:

```
- name: Print Hosts 2
  debug: msg={{hostvars[item]['ec2_id']}}
  when: hostvars[item]['ec2_id'] is defined
  with_inventory_hostnames: all
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Konstantin!
What a stupid problem!
Not sure if localhost is the first in the list so the task failed at the beginning or if ansible checks the whole list first and then runs the loop.